# Python - Calculate result as string of * signs rather then number

Tags: python

How can i change the output of the result to give a string of * signs instead of a number. Example 2+2 = **** or 4+4= ********

```
#Promting input from the user

n1 = float(input("Enter the First Number: "))
n2 = float(input("Enter the Second Number: "))

#addition

print("{} + {} = ".format(n1, n2))
print(n1 + n2)
```

Comment: You mean `print("{} + {} = {}".format(n1, n2, '*' * len(str(n1 + n2))))`?

Comment: Or `print(f"{n1} + {n2} = {'*' * (n1 + n2)}")` if you change the inputs to `int`. Why are they float anyway?

Answer (score 0):

It appears from your example that you need int not float. So use this instead:

```
n1 = int(input("Enter the First Number: "))
n2 = int(input("Enter the Second Number: "))
des_char = '*'

print((n1 + n2) * des_char)
```

As user @Guy mentioned in the comments, I'm wondering why you need floats? What do you expect your result to be if n1 = 1.2 and n2 = 2.4 ? Please clarify how you want a result such as 3.6 to be printed as '*'.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i change the output of the result to give a string of * signs
> instead of a number. Example 2+2 = **** or 4+4= ********

Snippet:

```
n1 = int(input("Enter the First Number: "))
n2 = int(input("Enter the Second Number: "))

#addition
word = '*'

print(word * n1 + word * n2)


print(f'{n1} + {n2} = {word * n1}{word * n2}')
```

Output:

```
2 + 2 = ****
```

If you enter 5 + 5:

Output:

```
5 + 5 = **********
```

If you enter 4 + 4:

Output:

```
4 + 4 = ********
```